# Postman - How to extract the pair of a variable value from an object (that is being selected at random)

Tags: postman, extract, postman-testcase

I have below response, from which I randomize the uuids in an env variable (as they are required in another request). Now I need to extract the title after I have the coresponding uuid

```
"data": [
        {
            "uuid": "14a12361-7057-4fb6-a4db-d234d39612a9",
            "title": "Male"
        },
        {
            "uuid": "5305f671-9a99-4c35-9703-9ea01e86d75d",
            "title": "Female"
        },
        {
            "uuid": "ff8d370g-d799-4ddf-ba97-e1c56624cdb0",
            "title": "Other"
        }
    ]
```

ex if I get the uuid of the first object I need the corresponding title, in this case: Male.

I have no idea how to do it, as I only found questions/answers on how to extract a value, but not how to extract the pair of another one.
Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: It's not very clear whether the `uuid` will always be random, if so then you can't use it as key.

Comment: probably I have not explained it properly.. but it will be one of the 3 from the above array. Those values will change with each request, so the stored value will change for every call done to this endpoint.
I use the uuid to generate a new user and I also have to add the "title" so I was thiunking that it wouldn't make much sense to randomize the title in the same way I did with the uuid, since the chance of them matching is slim. So I was thinking that there has to be a way to pair them up somehow.